# if mysql result does not exist echo?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi ive got a basic likes system on my site. Basically once the user clicks like, this sets user_id-has_liked to 1 from 0.

if their user_id_has_liked is set to 0 it displays the like link, if its set to 1 it displays unlike. however i want to add another condition that says if result is not in mysql then echo out the like link.

can someone show me where and what i would add to make this happen please.

```
<div class="profile_likes">
<?php
$user_like_set = user_like_status();
while ($like = mysql_fetch_array($user_like_set)) 
if ($like['user_id_has_liked'] == '0')  { ?>

<a href="like_profile.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>">Like</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<?

$count_likes_set = count_likes();
while ($likes = mysql_fetch_array($count_likes_set)) {

    echo "". $likes['likes'] ." People Like ".$profile[2]."";

    //$check_new_duos_set = check_new_escort_duos(); while ($newd = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_duos_set)) { 

    ?>

    <? } }?>



    <?php
$user_like_set = user_like_status();
while ($like = mysql_fetch_array($user_like_set)) 
if ($like['user_id_has_liked'] == '1')  { ?>

<a href="unlike_profile.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>">Unlike</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<?

$count_likes_set = count_likes();
while ($likes = mysql_fetch_array($count_likes_set)) {

    echo "". $likes['likes'] ." People Like ".$profile[2]."";

    //$check_new_duos_set = check_new_escort_duos(); while ($newd = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_duos_set)) { 
    ?>

    <? } }?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to strive for consistency in your usage of the echo/print functions and emulating them by terminating the php tag, your code will become much clearer.

```
<?php
    function printLikeLink($likeLink){
          echo "<a href='{$likeLink}'>Like this profile</a>";
    }
    $user_like_set = user_like_status();
    if ($like = mysql_fetch_array($user_like_set)){
        if ($like['user_id_has_liked'] == '1')  {
            echo "<a href=\"unlike_profile.php?to={$profile_id}\">Unlike</a>|";
            $count_likes_set = count_likes();
            while ($likes = mysql_fetch_array($count_likes_set)) {
                echo "". $likes['likes'] ." People Like ".$profile[2]."";
                //$check_new_duos_set = check_new_escort_duos(); while ($newd = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_duos_set)) { 
            }
        }else printLikeLink("like_profile.php?to={$profile_id}");
    }else printLikeLink("like_profile.php?to={$profile_id}"); // Edit this link.
?>
```

Comment: This wont work as mysql_fetch_array will return false if no record is found and hence it wont get inside loop.

Comment: Ah very true, thanks. If he is merely looking for a single entry as his code suggests he can replace the while with an if statement and add another else clause.

Comment: so can someone please show me what i need to do, im very confused. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php). It will give you number of rows present in the record set.
Besides that, a word of caution, the APIs you are using are deprecated. Look for suggested alternative on mysql site.

Answer (score 0):

try this i just made one change that your user_like_status(); should return true or false

```
<div class="profile_likes">
<?php
    $user_like_set = user_like_status();//should return true or false
    if ($user_like_set == false){
        $what = "Like"; 
    }else{
        $what = "Unlike";
    }?>    
    <a href="like_profile.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>"><?php echo $what ;?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php 
    $count_likes_set = count_likes();
    while ($likes = mysql_fetch_array($count_likes_set)) {
    echo "". $likes['likes'] ." People Like ".$profile[2]."";
    }
 ?>
</div>
```